# Quote Document size

Tags: apex, quote

I'd like to retrieve the size of quote document without retrieving actual content. Say, for attachments it's pretty easy:

```
SELECT BodyLength FROM Attachment WHERE Id = 'something'
```

But [QuoteDocument](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_quotedocument.htm) object in Salesforce doesn't have any size related field, only Document content itself.
So, my question: is there is method to retrieve size of quote document without retrieving the content?

Answer (score 3):

I believe if you setup **your specific salesforce instance URL** under the Remote Site Settings you should be able to utilize the HttpRequest/HttpResponse classes in Apex to call out to REST. The REST interface should then be able to bring back the ContentSize of the specific Document/Attachment that you have, without actually loading the file into memory.

If you go down that path take a look here which will get you started: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts

Then since you are already logged into Salesforce you should be able to use the existing SessionID in your HTTP Headers. I believe that Userinfo.getSessionId() will do that trick. I don't have any code to share on this, but hope if you decide to go this route that this helps.

Comment: Didn't occur to me to do it as a callout from Apex, nice one!

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly pretty but you could get some idea of the size but just checking the length of the `Document` field (though you'd need to know it's not going to blow out your heap space).

[There's an answer on StackOverflow which has a method to get an upper bound for the size of a base64 encoded file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6816206/481044):

> The exact length cannot be calculated unless you look at the padding.
>   Without looking for padding, the best you can do is calculate an upper
>   bound for the length by multiplying the encoded-string length with 3/4
>   (the encoded length is guaranteed to be exactly divisible by 4).
>
> The upper bound calculated thus will be either N, N+1 or N+2, where N
>   is the length of the raw data.

One way to not blow the heap would be to do this outside of the platform, potentially via Javascript in a Visualforce page for instance, or (stretching it a little) do it somewhere like Heroku and update some field that indicates the size of each document back in the org.

Comment: Agreed, but that means I have to read it, i.e. load to memory and use some heap. Document can be large.